# How to output line if row not exist

Tags: sql-server

Two Tables which are linked by the column ItemNumber.
First Table (name Items) with ItemNumbers, second one with colors (Tablename Color). Available colors for every Item is red, blue, green and black.

Every Item must have all 4 colors at the color Table.
If not, the Query should output the Itemnumber and the missing color.
For every missed color, one output line.

Don't know if there is a possibility to output such a messed up situation.

Hopefully somebody can give me a hint.

Comment: Can you give sample of your tables, expected result, and your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a many-to-many relationship, which means every row in the `items` table can be linked with multiple rows in the `colors` table, while every row in the `colors` table can be linked with multiple rows in the `items` table.

The correct way to create such a relationship in a relational database is to use three tables: One table for `items`, one table for `colors`, and one table for `itemToColor` (known as a bridge table) - which will have two columns - the item id and the color id, both referencing the other tables using a one-to-many foreign key constraint, and the combination of both is the primary key of the bridge table:

```
Item
-----
Id, (PK)
Name
(any other item related columns here)

Color
----
Id, (PK)
Name
(any other color related columns here)

ItemToColor
----
ItemId (FK To Items)
ColorId (FK To Colors)
PRIMARY KEY (ItemId, ColorId)
```

Using this structure, the answer to your question becomes trivial - you want to test if the record count of the `ItemToColor` table equals the multiplication of the record counts of the other tables:

```
IF
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ItemToColor) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Item) * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Color)

    -- All items have all colors.
```

Answer (score 2):

To show a row the row *needs to exists somewhere*, either from a physical table or created in the go on your script. You can create these colors on the go with a table variable (`DECLARE @Color TABLE (Color VARCHAR(20))` and a few inserts) or with a `VALUES` table:

```
SELECT
    C.Color
FROM
    (VALUES
        ('Red'),
        ('Green'),
        ('Blue'),
        ('Black')
    ) AS C (Color)
```

Now we `CROSS JOIN` all these colors with `Items`, this join will result on all colors that need to exists with each Item.

```
;WITH ForcedColors AS
(
    SELECT
        C.Color
    FROM
        (VALUES
            ('Red'),
            ('Green'),
            ('Blue'),
            ('Black')
        ) AS C (Color)
)
SELECT
    I.ItemNumber,
    FC.Color
FROM
    Items AS I
    CROSS JOIN ForcedColors AS FC
```

Now with this set we use `LEFT JOIN` against the actual available colors for each item, so a row will match if the color exists on table `Color`, or return `NULL` if it doesn't.

```
;WITH ForcedColors AS
(
    SELECT
        C.Color
    FROM
        (VALUES
            ('Red'),
            ('Green'),
            ('Blue'),
            ('Black')
        ) AS C (Color)
)
SELECT
    I.ItemNumber,
    ForcedColor = FC.Color,
    AvailableColor = C.Color
FROM
    Items AS I
    CROSS JOIN ForcedColors AS FC
    LEFT JOIN Color AS C ON
        I.ItemNumber = C.ItemNumber AND
        FC.Color = C.Color
```

Now to display the colors that are missing, just display those that have `NULL` from the `Color` table.

```
;WITH ForcedColors AS
(
    SELECT
        C.Color
    FROM
        (VALUES
            ('Red'),
            ('Green'),
            ('Blue'),
            ('Black')
        ) AS C (Color)
)
SELECT
    I.ItemNumber,
    ForcedColor = FC.Color,
    AvailableColor = C.Color
FROM
    Items AS I
    CROSS JOIN ForcedColors AS FC
    LEFT JOIN Color AS C ON
        I.ItemNumber = C.ItemNumber AND
        FC.Color = C.Color
WHERE
    C.Color IS NULL
```

Or another approach is to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `WHERE C.Color IS NULL`.

```
;WITH ForcedColors AS
(
    SELECT
        C.Color
    FROM
        (VALUES
            ('Red'),
            ('Green'),
            ('Blue'),
            ('Black')
        ) AS C (Color)
)
SELECT
    I.ItemNumber,
    ForcedColor = FC.Color
FROM
    Items AS I
    CROSS JOIN ForcedColors AS FC
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'color not available' FROM Color AS C 
                WHERE I.ItemNumber = C.ItemNumber AND FC.Color = C.Color)
```